# Append DIV (specified by class) inside other DIV (specified by other class)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, appendto

I have HTML sheets "A" and "B".
(HTML sheet "B" is read into html sheet "A". "A" works as a "template" for the very **varying** content in "B".)

I have this `div` in HTML sheet "A".

```
 <div class="productsheet-container">
 </div>
```

I add this `div` to HTML sheet "B":

```
<div class="productsheet">
          hello
</div>
```

This is my **required outcome**:

```
 <div class="productsheet-container">
      <div class="productsheet">
              hello
      </div>
 </div>
```

The `div class="productsheet"` should be **hidden from its original position**. So only be visible inside `div class="productsheet-container"`.

If anyone could help me here, I'd be forever grateful!
What JavaScript do I use **exactly**? Note! I'm a **COMPLETE NEWB** to JavaScript, haven't written one single line in my life! So, to me, the answers I've found googling seem insufficient.

I've, for example, tried:

```
$( ".productsheet-container" ).append( $( "<div class='productsheet' />" ) );
```

But shouldn't I write something before and/or after too?

Comment: I don't really get the problem this is supposed to solve. What feature are you trying to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this with just CSS:

```
.productsheet{
    display:none;
}
.productsheet-container .productsheet{
    display:block;
}
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H9625/)

To do the second part you can use this:

```
$(".productsheet-container").append($('.productsheet'));
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7XheE/)**

Comment: Thank you Sergio, I will use your CSS in combination with a jQuery solution. The productsheet still needs to appear in its right place first. :)

Comment: @Frida, just updated my answer with the second part you need.

Comment: @Frida, fick du till den?

Comment: @Frida ;) bra! glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

USE this:

```
$(".productsheet-container" ).append("<div class='productsheet'></div>");
```

[.append() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshjain24/Dm5J2/179/)

I would suggest you to learn plain javascript first,and then get on jQuery.

Comment: @user2758614:its pretty simple,and to add css you can give style in css file or inline...but as mentioned learn javascript first,all good developers do that!!

Comment: Thank you, Opus, I won't happen though. Should one of these lines be sufficient on its own just like that?

I guess your right about learning javascript :)

Comment: Opus, thank you for the fiddle! But I'm not creating the div content in the javascript. The content in the "div productsheet" will be collected from the html sheet "B" and will vary for differnt products (using the code in a shop).

Comment: @Frida:yes i know,but from your question it appeared as if you were trying to do it with jquery..its good if you can solve it with css itself..but this is also an elegant solution..

Comment: Opus, my problem is not solved...i can't solve it with only CSS. The CSS only solves the hide/show issue. But collecting the content from "B" and place it in a certain spot in "A", is still a mystery. Your snippet seems to create a div inside "productsheet-container", but not moving the div "productsheet" from one spot to another. Any further clues? :)

Comment: Look,this is what its is doing..Dont add any markup for the inner div...jquery will create a div and place it in a certain spot in a div...dont worry about that..just get rid of the div in html ..add it by jquery and style it the way you want it to...simple..and dont accept your answers untill your problems are solved..

Comment: I see, it's just that i need to use this as a template. Thats why i cant put exact content into the javascript, cause this code will be read by different products with different actual referring productsheets.

Comment: @Frida:look,dont overcompllicate things...what you have done uptill now is correct...just include one more line ..the above line...thats it..i have understood what you want...its pretty clear from your question..and feel free to tick this answer as correct if you think it helped

Comment: Outmost grateful for your efforts. Sergio's updated answer did the trick! :)

Answer (score 0):

Create the `div` as template and hidden from view using `style="display:none"`

```
<div id="template" class="productsheet-container" style="display:none">
   hello
 </div>
```

In your Javascript, clone the template, set `display:block` and append to `.productsheet-container` whenever you need.

```
$( ".productsheet-container" ).append( $("#template").clone().css("display","block" ));
```

Comment: This seem to answer whet I need, but I can't exactly get it to work. Would you mind showing me with a jsfiddle? :)